# Calling Error callback in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it possible to just simply trigger or call the error callback of save in backbone?

I'm overriding the save function of backbone with this

```
save: function(attributes, options) {
            options || (options = {});
            options.timeout    = 10000;    
            options.beforeSend = sendAuthorization;
            console.log( options.connection.ConnectionType );
            if( options.connection.ConnectionType != 'No network connection' ){
                Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(this, attributes, options);
            }else{
                console.log("ERROR! network related!");
            }
    }
```

options.connection.ConnectionType is simple a string which states the current internet connection of the device (iPad).

```
this.model.save( this.model, 
  connection : { ConnectionType : "No network connection" },
  success    : {...},
  error      : {...}
}
```

What I want is if the if statement failed then it should trigger the error callback of the save function. Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its simplest you can just execute the `error` callback function:

```
if( options.connection.ConnectionType != 'No network connection' ){
    Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(this, attributes, options);    
} else {
    if(options.error) {
        options.error(this, null, options);
    }
}
```

This method has the problem that it doesn't comply to the `save` method and `error` callback API. The `save` method is expected to return an `jqXHR` object, and the error callback is expected to have it as the second argument.

If you want to provide an API compatible method/callback signature, the simplest way would be to abort the request. Something like:

```
var xhr = Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(this, attributes, options);
if( options.connection.ConnectionType == 'No network connection' ){
    xhr.abort();
}
return xhr;
```

This will cancel the request as soon as it is initiated. You get your xhr/promise return object and the correct xhr parameter to the callback. The `status` of the xhr will be 0 and `statusText` "abort".

Comment: I did what you suggest but if I successfully abort the request I can't seem to make any request afterwards.